# Rails Active Record group query in SQLite vs Postgres

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sqlite, activerecord

I am getting an error when running a query in SQLite vs Postgres with Active Record. There is an aggregate function error in Postgres but nothing in SQLite. My question is, what is SQLite doing here? Is it ignoring the group? Notice that GROUP BY "song" doesn't return an error.

### SQLite output:

**Playlist.where(user_id:user.id).group(:song)**

```
Playlist Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "playlists".* FROM "playlists" WHERE 
"playlists"."user_id" = ? GROUP BY "song"  [["user_id", 1]]

=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Playlist id: 2, user_id: 1, song_id: 1, 
created_at: "2017-04-27 01:18:01", updated_at: "2017-04-27 01:18:01">]>
```

**Playlist.where(user_id:user.id).group(:song_id)**

```
 Playlist Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "playlists"."id", "playlists"."user_id",
 "playlists"."song_id" FROM "playlists" WHERE "playlists"."user_id" = ?
 GROUP BY "song"  [["user_id", 1]]

  => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Playlist id: 2, user_id: 1, song_id: 
  1, created_at: "2017-04-27 01:18:01">]>
```

**Playlist.where(user_id:user.id).group(:id,:song_id)**

```
 Playlist Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "playlists".* FROM "playlists" WHERE 
 "playlists"."user_id" = ? GROUP BY "playlists"."id", 
 "playlists"."song_id"  [["user_id", 1]]

 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Playlist id: 1, user_id: 1, song_id: 1, 
 created_at: "2017-04-27 01:18:00", updated_at: "2017-04-27 01:18:00">, 
 #<Playlist id: 2, user_id: 1, song_id: 1, created_at: "2017-04-27 
 01:18:01", updated_at: "2017-04-27 01:18:01">]>
```

**Playlist.where(user_id:user.id).group(:song).count**

```
 (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, "playlists"."song_id" AS      
 playlists_song_id FROM "playlists" WHERE "playlists"."user_id" = ? 
 GROUP BY "playlists"."song_id"  [["user_id", 1]]

 Song Load (2.1ms)  SELECT  "songs".* FROM "songs" 
 WHERE "songs"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]] 

 => {#<Song id: 1, title: "A song", artist: "Artist", user_id: 1, 
 created_at: "2017-04-27 01:17:39">=>2}
```

### Postgres:

**Playlist.where(user_id:user.id).group(:song_id)**

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column 
"playlists.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an 
aggregate function

SELECT "playlists".* FROM "playlists" WHERE "playlists"."user_id" = $1 
GROUP BY "playlists"."song_id"
```

**Playlist.where(user_id:user.id).group(:id,:song_id)**

```
 Playlist Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "playlists".* FROM "playlists" WHERE 
 "playlists"."user_id" = $1 GROUP BY "playlists"."id",      
 "playlists"."song_id"  [["user_id", 1]]

 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Playlist id: 1, user_id: 1, song_id: 1, 
 created_at: "2017-04-27 01:25:34", updated_at: "2017-04-27 01:25:34">, 
 #<Playlist id: 2, user_id: 1, song_id: 1, created_at: "2017-04-27 
 01:25:36", updated_at: "2017-04-27 01:25:36">]>
```

**Playlist.where(user_id:user.id).group(:song).count**

```
 (0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, "playlists"."song_id" AS 
 playlists_song_id FROM "playlists" WHERE "playlists"."user_id" = $1 
 GROUP BY "playlists"."song_id"  [["user_id", 1]]

 Song Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "songs".* FROM "songs" WHERE "songs"."id" = 
 $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]

 => {#<Song id: 1, title: "A song", artist: "Artist", user_id: 1, 
 created_at: "2017-04-27 01:25:26", updated_at: "2017-04-27           
 01:25:26">=>2}
```

Comment: I have looked at other questions but mine is more focused on what and why is SQLite doing what it is doing. It seems to be ignoring the group clause of the SQL statement. I didn't mention anything about deploying. I simply switched to Postgres during development, as I forgot to give it the Postgres flag on rails new. I also have the proper aggregate queries in the question.

Answer (score 0):

A common rule for `group by`: you may select only columns listed in `group by` and aggregate functions. This approach supported by sql standard and will work in any sql database.

If you are selecting columns not listed in a `group by` clause, for example `select * … group by song_id`, it may work in some databases and will not work in others.

If you specify selected columns in your code it will work:

```
Playlist.
  where(user_id:user.id).
  select("song_id").
  group(:song_id)
```

You may read details about `group by` in PostgreSQL documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY